# Laravel: Database SQLite does not exists

Tags: laravel, sqlite

I created a sqlite using **vim** and it created *database.sqlite.swp*. Then i configure the **.env** *DB_Connection to sqlite*.

Afterwards, I run php artisan serve and php artisan migrate but i got error :
**Database (C:Laravel/Project/database/database.sqlite) does not exist.**

Vim v8.2
Laravel v4

Please help me :<

Answer (score 1):

You have to create new file in this path (C:Laravel/Project/database/) and name it **database.sqlite**